# Should I specify &block argument in def?

Tags: ruby, coding-style, arguments, block, function

In Ruby, is it better (style?) to specify that your method takes `&block` or not?

The choice merely seems to be a matter of style so long as the method body contains `yield`.

For example, given:

```
def abc1(a, c)
  puts a
  yield
  puts c
end

def abc2(a, c, &block)
  puts a
  yield
  puts c
end
```

the following two calls:

```
abc1('a', 'c') { puts 'b' }
abc2('a', 'c') { puts 'b' }
```

each print and return the same things:

```
a
b
c
=> nil
```

So, if it's really just a matter of style, what's the convention (or better style)?

Answer (score 5):

With your current code first one is better. While you are using `yield` then, no need to use `&block`, as it is *implicit*. But yes, one thing to remind, you have to pass a block while using `yield`, if not then there will be error. Although that error can be handled using [`block_given?`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/block_given%3F).

Ruby's `yield` statement gives control to a user specified block from the method's body. So, if you are using again `&block` it is redundant, so don't need to use it.

Answer (score 3):

It is important to remember that the main reason to pass the block as a parameter is that it is converted to an object (an instance of the class [Proc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Proc.html)), so it can be passed on:

```
def ab(&block)
  yield "ab"
  cd(&block)
end

def cd(&block)
  yield "cd"
  block.call("cd")
end

ab { |str| puts "In #{str}. Please pass the salt, the pepper and the proc." }
In ab. Please pass the salt, the pepper and the proc.
In cd. Please pass the salt, the pepper and the proc.
In cd. Please pass the salt, the pepper and the proc.
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of personal taste.  The two common cases are as follows:

```
def abc1(a, c)
  puts a
  yield
  puts c
end
```

Often `yield` is used when the block is passed implicitly, as in this example.  The other you commonly see is

```
def abc2(a, c, &block)
  puts a
  block.call(args)
  puts c
end
```

The advantage to this is that someone reading your code can easily see that a block needs to be passed.